# Trouble with definition of nuclear spaces from Hilbert seminorms.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space), we have

> If $p$ is a seminorm on $V$, we write $V_p$ for the Banach space given by completing $V$ using the seminorm $p$. There is a natural map from $V$ to $V_p$ (not necessarily injective).
>
> We will say that a seminorm $p$ is a Hilbert seminorm if $V_p$ is a Hilbert space, or equivalently if $p$ comes from a sesquilinear positive semidefinite form on $V$.

I am having trouble interpreting the above. First the completion of a vector space with respect to a *seminorm* is... what exactly?
Then, $V_p$ is supposedly a *Hilbert space* which would require positive definitness and not just semi-definiteness.

Do the authors mean that $V_p$ is the completion of $V / \mathrm{ker} \, p$ with respect to the *norm* induced by $p$?

Also, I have not managed to find any reference on this Hilbert space definition of nuclear spaces except for [Blanchard, Brüning](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-14045-2_29). But they use actual *norms* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a reference in some [lecture notes](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.020/fackler/SS15/qm/lnotes_mathematical_found_qm_temp.pdf). Apparently, one does mean to define $V_p$ as the completion of $V/\mathrm{ker} \, p$ with respect to the norm induced by $p$.